# Yaml file returning null in Gatsby Graphql query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, yaml, gatsby

I've this Gatsby project where I'd like to source the content from local Yaml files. I've installed gatsby-transformer-yaml and it seems to work ok, but my test file is returning null results. I'm not sure why.

Here's the content of the file hero.yaml

```
# hero.yaml
- titulo: Titulo principal.
- subtitulo: Titulo secundário
- botao: Texto do botão
```

And its results in my graphql IDE:
[image]

As you can see, the first item is returning ok. Not sure what's happening to the others.
Any ideas of what could be? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that my Yaml formatting was wrong. There's no dash for every line start. Here's the proper way.

```
# hero.yaml
- titulo: Título principal
  subtitulo: Título secundário
  botao: Texto do botão
```